# Sudoku algorithm with unfamiliar java syntax

Tags: java

I was looking through a Sudoku solving algorithm when I came across a line with some syntax I haven't seen before.

The line I'm confused about is

```
    System.out.print(solution[i][j] == 0 ? " " : Integer.toString(solution[i][j]));
```

I do not understand what the question mark means or anything after the question mark.
This line is part of the method

```
    static void writeMatrix(int[][] solution) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            System.out.println(" -----------------------");
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {
            if (j % 3 == 0)
                System.out.print("| ");
            System.out.print(solution[i][j] == 0 ? " " : Integer.toString(solution[i][j]));

            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        System.out.println("|");
    }
    System.out.println(" -----------------------");
}
```

I got this code from http://www.colloquial.com/games/sudoku/java_sudoku.html. Any explanations would be appreciated!

Comment: Look up the ternary operator. For example, please check out [this link](http://java.about.com/b/2009/06/06/java-term-of-the-week-ternary-operator.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is standard [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Java), which is present in most languages: C, C++, Java, Perl, etc.

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 System.out.print(solution[i][j] == 0 ? " " : Integer.toString(solution[i][j]));
```

is identical to

```
    if(solution[i][j] == 0){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    else{
        System.out.print(Integer.toString(solution[i][j]));
    }
```

It is basically an inline way to write an if/else statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's an if statement basically. It will print out `" "` if `solution[i][j] == 0` and `Integer.toString(solution[i][j])` if its not.

Answer (score 0):

Basically says that if that value is 0, print " ", if not, print the string representation of whatever that array is storing.